# Firebase Websocket Exception : error while creating secure socket

Tags: java, android, firebase, nest-api

During firebase authentication using "Firebase.authWithCustomToken()" it is giving following **error**

> " WebSocket: ws_9 - had an error:
>   com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: error while creating secure
>   socket to
>   wss://firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/.ws?ns=developer-api&v=5"

**The json response is :**

> {d={r=0, b={s=unauthorized,
>   d={"error":"unauthorized","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#auth-error","message":"unauthorized","instance":"2de0e6ce-5368-4160-b40c-d2131f2c0d65"}}},
>   t=d} Tue Dec 01 11:25:55 IST 2015 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 -
>   received data message: {r=0, b={s=unauthorized,
>   d={"error":"unauthorized","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#auth-error","message":"unauthorized","instance":"2de0e6ce-5368-4160-b40c-d2131f2c0d65"}}}

While i have provided right accessToken during Firebase.authWithCustomToken() method call.

It seems that firebase api is unable to make conenction to nest cloud .Please help for the same

Comment: What version of the Firebase client library are you using? Nest only works with version 1.x of the Firebase client libraries, while Firebase has since move to a 2.x. To ensure you get a compatible version, start from the [Nest client libraries page](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/firebase-client-libraries).

Comment: I post an question like yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634483/android-firebase-login-takes-a-bit-long-and-websocketexception-occurred