# Android, Firebase login takes a bit long and WebSocketException occurred

Tags: websocket, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using **authWithCustomToken** method to login with Firebase. Login takes approximately 5 seconds or more. I enabled Firebase log (*setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)*) for monitoring is there a any problem. Log is here (I trimmed a bit, if necessary i can give a link for it):

*PS: android firebase client version is 2.5.0*

```
ws_0 - websocket opened
conn_0 - Got control message: {t=r, d=s-softlayer.firebaseio.com}
conn_0 - Got a reset; killing connection to tbf.firebaseio.com; Updating internalHost to s-softlayer.firebaseio.com
conn_0 - closing realtime connection
handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={t=r, d=s-softlayer.firebaseio.com}, t=c}
ws_0 - websocket is being closed
ws_0 - had an error
    com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO Error
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.run(WebSocketReceiver.java:78)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(WebSocket.java:372)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(WebSocket.java:30)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(WebSocket.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:99)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.read(WebSocketReceiver.java:141)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.run(WebSocketReceiver.java:34)
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(WebSocket.java:372) 
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(WebSocket.java:30) 
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(WebSocket.java:108) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 

ws_0 - |IO Error|
ws_0 - closed

conn_1 - Opening a connection
ws_1 - websocket opened
ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={t=r, d=s-dal5-nss-19.firebaseio.com}, t=c}
conn_1 - Got control message: {t=r, d=s-dal5-nss-19.firebaseio.com}
conn_1 - Got a reset; killing connection to s-softlayer.firebaseio.com; Updating internalHost to s-dal5-nss-19.firebaseio.com
conn_1 - closing realtime connection
ws_1 - websocket is being closed
ws_1 - had an error
    com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO Error
        at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.run(WebSocketReceiver.java:78)
        ...
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
        ...

ws_1 - |IO Error|
ws_1 - closed
conn_2 - Opening a connection
ws_1 - had an error
    com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO Exception
    ...
ws_1 - |IO Exception|
ws_2 - websocket opened
conn_2 - Got control message: {t=h, d={ts=1452086065546, v=5, h=s-dal5-nss-19.firebaseio.com, s=EaQhQ7iRAjeWVxvzBJEFD7k4TKFsmrms}}
conn_2 - realtime connection established
```

Is this log saying there is an error?

Should I ignore it? If yes, why login takes too long?

Answer (score 3):

There is no information in the output to determine any timing impact. But as far as I can tell the flow looks normal. Your first two connections are being redirected. The third connection then reaches the correct server, which responds with "realtime connection established".

Comment: But, always first two connection fails. The third successful. Thats weird, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, that is normal as far as I know. On the initial connection, you access a "random" Firebase server. Since this is not likely the server that you need, you get redirect to the correct server. For various reasons that is a two-step process in your case. But IIRC the final server name should be stored after the first time it establishes a realtime connection.

Comment: The problem is this occurs everytime, not sometime. I will comment for updates. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, I tested yesterday and it indeed happens on every restart. But these redirects are normal and are not by definition slow. So instead of focussing on the redirects, I would focus on where the time goes. What is your latency to each of the servers involved? For comparison, my `ping s-dal5-nss-19.firebaseio.com` and `ping s-softlayer.firebaseio.com` are about 40-60ms each.

Comment: You are right, redirects not take long time. But authWithCustomLogin takes approximately 7 seconds. Is it normal, too? What can I do to decrease this time?

Comment: Weird thing is, If I run application on my phones login takes 7 seconds. But on genymotion emulator, it takes 1 second. Phones and emulator connected same wireless network..

Comment: I just added a simple activity that runs `authWithCustomToken` to [this Github repo](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android). It's `Activity34634483`, after the id of this question. Over wifi it authenticates within 1 second on a Nexus 7 (it fact, about 0.2s according to the logcat output). Over 3G the first auth takes between 5 and 15 seconds, subsequents are 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I found the problem. There is keepSyned(true) line before login. If I remove it, firebase authenticate within 1 second.

Comment: Huh? Really? That is very unexpected. :-/ I'll see if I can reproduce. Thanks for reporting back, it might be worth writing that as an answer (with the tiny code snippet showing the order of the statements that solves the problem).

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope you can find what is causing that :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is doing authentication after *`keepSynced(true)`* line. Synced node has approximately 250KB data. I think syncing the data blocks my authentication. On the other hand, firebase can not sync the node because it has to authenticate for reading the node.(looks like deadlock) I'm not sure what the actual reason but removing `keepSynced(true)` line fixed my problem for now.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("my_firebase_url");
ref.child("matches").keepSynced(true); // removed this line
ref.authWithCustomToken(...);
```